# Not able to create SSIS DB Catlog in linux RHEL 7

Tags: sql-server, linux, ssis, rhel, rhel7

I am not able to create SSIS DB Catalog on my MS SQL Server which is installed on Linux RHEL 7 Server. Though I have installed SSIS on Linux RHEL 7.

Whenever I am trying to create SSIS DB Catalog i am getting this error.

---

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

The path to the catalog backup file could not be determined. Integration Services might not be installed on this server, or the user may not have the appropriate access permissions. (Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Common.ObjectModel)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProductVersion=15.0.900.30+((SQL_Main).180917-0221)&LinkId=20476

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the documentation: [Extract, transform, and load data on Linux with SSIS - Deploy Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-ssis?view=sql-server-2017#deploy-packages)

> You can only store packages in the file system on Linux in this
>   release. The SSIS Catalog database and the legacy SSIS service are not
>   available on Linux for package deployment and storage.

Currently (at the time of writing this post), if you want to run an SSIS package on SQL Server on Linux you **must** use the file system deployment method, no other methods are supported.

If you are planning to use SSIS on SQL Server on Linux, I suggest having a read of [Limitations and known issues for SSIS on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-ssis-known-issues?view=sql-server-2017). The list is quite extensive.